# Make correct use of the OpenXML to write justified

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word, openxml

I need help in writing justified using OpenXML in Word. My application does handle some data and should afterwards write the output (which are texts) in a .docx-file (Word file).
Since I am new to OpenXML and since I do not want to reply on 3rd party plugins I want to stick to the simplest solution possible.

After my application processed the data, I have for example three texts:
Text1="Automation code 83743 on 2022-08-04 @ 091433"
Text2="The power of the three samples provides no significant changes during the last period of test"
Text3="Sample A=8458349mg/L, Sample B=849922mg/L,....Sample Z48=798993mg/L"

I want the following:
Text1 should be written simply in **bold**.
Text2 should be written simply in **bold** too.
Text3 should be written as justified text without being bold.

Currently my code looks like this (as the documentation I found uses the same sort of coding):

```
Dim WordDocumentPath As String = "C:\\Text.docx"

'Create a document to work in
 Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(WordDocumentPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
    ' Add a main document part.
    Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()

    ' Create the document structure and add some text.
    mainPart.Document = New Document()
    Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
    Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
    Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
        
    'Write bold
    Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))

    run.AppendChild(New Text(Text1))
    run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)

    'Write bold
    run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
    run.AppendChild(New Text(Text2))
    run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)

    'Write justified
    run.AppendChild(New Text(Text3))
    run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)
         
    Next
End Using
```

I have the problem that using my code, I am somehow not able to write in justified. Is there a nicer way to write my code (in regards to optimization)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.Use **Justification** and **ParagraphProperties**.

```
        Dim WordDocumentPath As String = "C:\\Text.docx"

    'Create a document to work in
    Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(WordDocumentPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
        ' Add a main document part.
        Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()

        ' Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = New Document()
        Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
        Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
        Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())

        Dim justification As Justification = New Justification()
        justification.Val = JustificationValues.Center
        Dim paragraphProperties1 As ParagraphProperties = New ParagraphProperties
        paragraphProperties1.Append(justification)
        Dim paragraph As Paragraph = New Paragraph
        paragraph.ParagraphProperties = paragraphProperties1

        'Write bold
        Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
        run.AppendChild(New Text("11111111111111111"))
        run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)
        'Write bold

        run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
        run.AppendChild(New Text("22222222222222222222"))
        run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)
        'Write justified
        run.AppendChild(New Text("33333333333333333333"))
        run.AppendChild(paragraph)
        wordDocument.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error. On the line:  `run.AppendChild(paragraph)` the following message is thrown: Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.